# Removing :notice and <div> in Rails 3.1 app on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap

This might be an easy one for you guys, but I'm not sure the best way to achieve it.

Is there some type of `.erb` I can write that asks "If `:notice` is present, then render..."?

*Here's more about the issue:*

My controller specifies a `:notice` for both the `create` and `update` actions (pretty standard).  When I load the pages, the notices do as I'd expect and show up.  When I reload the page however, (not sure why someone would do this, but I did), the `:notice` goes away (great, that's what I want), but the containing `<div>` remains.

How do I go about ensuring that the encapsulating `<div>` is removed along with the `:notice`?  I'm not sure what conditionals to specify in my view or maybe controller.  The view looks something like this (btw, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap JS alerts).

**View**

```
<div class="alert-message success fade in" data-alert="alert">
  <a class="close" href"#">×</a>
  <p><%= notice %></p>
</div>
```

My **controller** is a single scaffolded model/resource with basic structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was:

```
<% if notice == "[:notice string]" %>
.
.
.
<% end %>
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient and "Rails-y" way to do it, but it worked for me.